# Assign a letter to a value if that value falls within a range of possible numbers

Tags: python

Simple question, but I can't figure out a way to assign a letter to an input number without using a whole bunch of if statements.

What I'm after is:

0-11 : A

12-23 : B

24-35 : C

and so on.

I first thought to use modulo, but that divides numbers sequentially between a range.

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
for i in range(95):
    if 0 < i < 12:
        well = letters[i%12]
```

Is there something similar to modulo I can use?

Comment: You need floor division not modulo.

Comment: Rather than edit the question to include the answer, post it as an answer. You are allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: Cheers, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as pointed out by blhsing, is to use floor division, which is x//y

In my case, dividing up letters into twelve segments would work out like this:

```
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
well = []

for i in range(95):
    well.append(letters[i//12])
```